# Get Github Enterprise Stats using API

Tags: github, github-api

i am trying to fetch statistics of GitHub instance using the below command as per https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/v3/enterprise-admin/admin_stats/

`curl -u username:password https://<hostname>/api/v3/enterprise/stats/:all`

However i am getting the below message. Please help me in fixing this issue

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.14/v3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the documentation states:

> It is only available to authenticated site administrators.
>   Normal users will receive a 404 response if they try to access it.

Check first if you are declared as a site admin on your GitHub Enterprise server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got sorted by removing  `:` (before all) in the api